# How to create thumbnail image in laravel using Intervention in live server?

Tags: laravel

My primary domain is xyz.com. I have created a folder named "test" outside public_html folder and uploaded the whole laravel set up there except the public folder which I have moved to public_html folder.
My folder structure is like this.
test -> contains the laravel project without public folder.
public_html -> contains the public folder.
However I cannot upload images. Error is showing like "Image source not readable". Please help.

```
if ($request->hasFile('frontimage')) {
    $file_frontimage = $request->file('frontimage');
    $actual_filename_frontimage = $file_frontimage->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename_frontimage = time() . '_' . $actual_filename_frontimage;
    $file_frontimage->storeAs('images', $filename_frontimage, 'public');
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your public folder is the public facing folder of your Laravel app. You can't just move it and expect it to work. I can't imagine what could be the reason of moving it in the first place.

Comment: I have made a project that contains admin part and front end. The admin part is being created in a laravel and kept inside a subdomain folder. The front end is my primary domain that is also created in laravel. Thats why I have kept the entire front end laravel project inside a "test" folder outside public_html directory without public folder and kept the public folder inside public_html folder. My subdomain folder is inside the public_html folder. I am trying to upload image from sub domain folder and save those to the primary domain.

Comment: filesystem.php in subdomain
'parent_disk' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => '/home/your_username/public_html/storage/app/public',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
if ($request->hasFile('frontimage')) {
            $file_frontimage->storeAs('thumbnailimages', '525x350'.$request->file('frontimage')->getClientOriginalName(), 'parent_disk');
            $thumbnailpath_525x350= public_path('storage/thumbnailimages/'.'525x350'.$filename_frontimage);
            $img_525x350= Image::make($thumbnailpath_525x350)->resize(525,350); @kopz